# How to write faster Python code?

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

My code

```
with open('data1.txt','r') as f:
    lst = [int(line) for line in f]

l1=lst[::3]
l2=lst[1::3]
l3=lst[2::3]

print len(l1)
print len(l2)
print len(l3)

b = []
for i in range(3200000):
    b.append(i+1)

print len(b)

mapping = dict(zip(l1, b))
matches = [mapping[value] for value in l2 if value not in mapping]
print matches
```

My aim here is two compare lists,they are expected to have same elements.
Works fine

```
3200000
3200000
3200000
3200000
[]
```

But problem is that the code is very slow and I will have more calculations later.How to improve this?
My python

```
Python 2.7.6
```

Comment: How slow is slow? How large are your data structures?

Comment: are you using python 2.x?  if so, change `range` to `xrange`, `range` creates list eat memories

Comment: Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for working with arrays of data.

Comment: @haifzhan even better, just do `b = xrange(3200000)`, there's no need to build the list, `zip` will consume the `xrange`. (obviously `print len(b)` would have to be removed)

Comment: You can also look up itertools

Comment: Can you include Python version in question / tags? If you're using 2.x you may get some performance improvements by using lazy forms of `range` and `zip` or introduce some `itertools` functions. Also, have you profiled your code? What's exactly a bottleneck here? Are you sure it's not file I/O?

Comment: @Rogalski: Based on the use of `print` as a statement, has to be Python 2.

Comment: @Rogalski It is 2.7.6. How to know where is bottleneck?

Comment: @RichardRublev https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: I can't edit my comment again, but to accurately reflect the questioner's code I should have written `b = xrange(1, 3200001)`

Comment: for the mapping dict creation with zip since you have equal len lists you could replace `dict(zip(l1, b))` with ``mapping = {}` and
`for i in xrange(1,3200001):
 mapping[l1[i-1]] = i`. 50% faster

Comment: Depending on what you need to do if the lists aren't equal, it's possible that using sets, in particular the `difference` method, might be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be as efficient regarding to memory but VERY efficient regarding execution speed.
It seems like you do not use l3. diff will have everything not contained in both lists.

```
import itertools
with open('data1.txt','r') as f:
    lines = map(int, f)

l1 = itertools.islice(lines, 0, None, 3)
l2 = itertools.islice(lines, 1, None, 3)
diff = set(l1) ^ set(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see how that can work:

```
[mapping[value] for value in l2 if value not in mapping]
```

I suppose the `value` is always in `mapping` and the array is always empty. It should throw an error otherwise since the key will not be found.

Then, try something like this, with no useless memory allocation:

```
mapping = {}
l2 = []

with open('data1.txt','r') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        v = int(line)
        if i % 3 == 0:
            mapping[v] = i+1
        elif i % 3 == 1:
            l2.append(v)

matches = [mapping[value] for value in l2 if value not in mapping] # ??

print(matches)
```

Comment: Your code is working.  File "b18.py", line 11, in <module>
    matches.append(mapping[v])
KeyError: 1207

Comment: Yes, because of my first remark. I don't know what you really wanted there. Correct the statement where I put the '# ??'.

Comment: Again problems. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b20.py", line 10, in <module>
    l2[i] = v
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Now I kept your own line (copied and pasted), just correct that one with what you wanted.

Comment: Index out of range means that `32000` is not the right number. If you have varying length, then `append` instead of filling the array first. I edited for that. It can be slower though, if the size grows big enough, because it may have to reallocate more memory somewhere else.